# How do I install DKMS (and others) for my NVidia drivers on Vivid?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04, dkms

Today I tried install Ubuntu again (I haven't succeeded in weeks!) and I need my NVidia drivers to my GeForce GTX 970.

I followed to simplest guide I could find:

> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-settings

The problem comes with the later command, where the output looks something like this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-352 : Depends: dkms but it's not installable
             Depends: lib32gcc1 but it's not installable
             Depends: libc6-i386 but it's not installed (I have no idea why bc I'm running AMD)
             Recommends: nvidia-prine (>= 0.5) but it's not installable or
                         bumblebee but it's not installed
             Recommends: libcuda1-352 but it's not installed
             Recommends: nvidia-opencl-icd-352 but it's not installed
nvidia-settings : Depends: screen-resolution-extra (>= 0.12) but it's not installable
                  Depends: libjansson4  (>= 2.3) but it's not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My sources.list looks like this:

```
deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main 
deb archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid univrse
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install dkms` (no installation candidates).
I don't have any graphics drivers at all so I need to everything from (`Ctrl + Alt + F1-F6`)-terminal.

I'm starting to go mad because everyone I see installing Ubuntu just press enter and done, no worries about graphics.

Comment: Something is wrong with your access to Ubuntu repositories. You probably need to change download mirror in System Settings -> Software & Updates.

Comment: I can't access any GUI, I'm stuck in terminal.

Comment: Add it yo your question, not here please.

Comment: Are there only 2 lines in your sources.list? Is there really both utopic an vivid?

Comment: Correct, is it supposed to be more on a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be much more. Where did you get the installation image from?

Comment: From "http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads" I choose Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop (64-bit) the torrent file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create some normal `sources.list`.
Run

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

and replace its contents with

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main multiverse universe restricted
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

and reboot. That should let you boot normally.

And after you boot to GUI, you can use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/167850) to re-create normal `sources.list`.

Comment: Thanks mate! 
I just passed my internet time. So downloading will take all night. (5-7kB/s)